# How are low level device drivers written for Linux?

Tags: linux, driver

I remember reading some books about Linux Device drivers around the end of my university education for Comp. Science. Soon there-after I got a job and haven't really worked much with Linux/Embedded (I do mostly java stuff now). However it's something I want to look into.

Anyways I recall reading an online article (ill edit post if I can find it) about writing a USB Driver for Linux for a Little "USB Missile Turret" similar to this:
http://www.thinkgeek.com/geektoys/warfare/8a0f/

Anyways it went into detail about how to write the driver without a driver being provided (the guy just found a generic one on ebay....and figured out how to like...write the driver just by looking at the components and such). ANYWAYS it was pretty amazing.

I have a pretty good clue about how low level embedded stuff works, but thats for stuff like AVR's/PIC Microcontrollers, I have no idea how something like this would be written for like a Normal processor in a PC.

Anyways I guess what Im asking is.....how do you figure out this kinda stuff, where would I find such information.

edit: found the link
http://matthias.vallentin.net/blog/2007/04/writing-a-linux-kernel-driver-for-an-unknown-usb-device/

(It's way more confusing then I thought, I didn't realize he reverse engineered a Windows USB driver..im guessing it'd be impossible to figure out without snooping through a windows driver?)

Comment: Check this out - but it only focus on one layer. http://free-electrons.com/doc/linux-usb.pdf

Comment: [this](http://free-electrons.com/doc/books/ldd3.pdf) is must read for driver development, have alot of fun like i do during the linux driver development ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Linux kernel and drivers](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.35/drivers) are [GDFL source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDFL).  You can read the code, change them, compile them, and experiment to your heart's delight with them.  That is a pretty good way to learn.

Comment: Are these resources still available and/or where can I locate something similar?