# Learning to write low level drivers (Linux).

Tags: c++, c, linux, driver

So I was fiddling around with the Raspberry Pi, and it just kinda came to me that "Where do all these drivers come from". Like specifically for the SNES controllers im using on them....how on earth did someone figure out how to write that.

I know C decently, and C++...ok. But this has always been something I kinda thought about. It's cool because it's low level enough to understand possibly whats going on hardware wise....but also great to learn about the OS.

Where do I start with something like this? Im guessing doing this for windows would be WAYYYY different.

Thanks

Comment: http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ Linux device drivers book

Comment: rml's [Linux Kernel Development](http://www.amazon.com/Linux-Kernel-Development-3rd-Edition/dp/0672329468) is worthwhile too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that there are really two questions here that don't really have a lot to do with each other.

The first is "what does Linux require of device drivers?" That's almost always going to be answered by reading the documentation. Although the device driver documentation may (arguably) be a little less thorough, complete, easy to read, etc., than docs for writing normal programs, it's still pretty decent. Probably the biggest difference from normal code is debugging, which is most often done via simply printing things out with `printk`.

The other question is something like: "How do you figure out what protocol is (or "protocols are") used by specific hardware like the SNES controller. When you're developing for something like a normal hard drive or keyboard, you can pretty much just follow the documentation. You may (often do, at least in my experience) find that you need to compensate for some bugs in the hardware, but beyond that it's (again) fairly normal programming. The biggest challenge in quite a few of these cases is simply deciding how you want to present the particular device in question to the rest of the system. For something like a hard drive that's generally pretty easy, but for something like a human interface device, it can be a little more challenging (e.g., do you want to present it as itself, or do you want to emulate some existing type of device like a keyboard or mouse?)

For hardware that's not really documented, things can get a little more difficult. The really general purpose tool for looking at logic signals is a logic analyzer. If you have something that uses a well-known hardware interface (e.g., PS/2 keyboard/mouse, USB, SATA) you can find more specialized tools (and/or add-ons for a logic analyzer) that make life quite a bit easier. Something like an NES or SNES controller almost certainly uses a proprietary interface, so for these you probably end up using a logic analyzer. Fortunately, they're also likely to be a pretty narrow, slow interface, so the logic analyzer doesn't need to be terribly fast or support a huge number of channels.

With the logic analyzer you can see all the individual signals, but for a proprietary interface, it's pretty much up to you to figure out which signals do what. In a typical case, you'll have at least a few that are fairly obvious: power, ground, quite possibly a clock, and so on. In quite a few cases, you quickly find that even if it's not publicly documented, it may follow some well-known protocol like I<sup>2</sup>C, SPI, etc.

Comment: Is using a logic analyzer difficult? is there a good resource for this that's well known?

Comment: @Mercfh: I don't find logic analyzers particularly difficult to use, but a lot depends on how elaborate you decide to get with triggers and such. You might want to look on the [EE site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) for more about them.

Comment: So ideally we'd use a Logic Analyzer to see what information is coming from (Like per se im using the SNES Controller example) the controller when I press each button, and then fit that into the Device Driver that you write.

Comment: @Mercfh: Yup, that's pretty much the idea.

Answer (score 2):

[Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) is the book you want.

While you wait for the book to arrive, I can tell you that knowing how the hardware works and how the Linux kernel works is only half the battle.  You also need to know the hardware level interface for your specific device.  Hopefully you can find documentation for this, but that can be difficult.

See this related question for an example of how someone came up with a driver for Linux by watching the commands that came out of the Windows driver: 
[How are low level device drivers written for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003117/how-are-low-level-device-drivers-written-for-linux)

For Windows, the process is not actually terribly different.  All the concepts are still the same, since it is the same hardware.  The differences are in the details, of course.